# Change Structure of Magento Product Meta Title

Tags: magento, title, meta, page-title

I am having some difficulty at the minute with Magento developing a site for my client.

Currently, the product title is [PRODUCT_NAME] | [PRODUCT_CATEGORY]

I would like to change this to say [PREFIX] [PRODUCT_NAME] [SUFFIX]

I know this can be done using Magento's prefix and suffix pages however I want this to only apply to *products*. Any ideas how I can implement this without it being overwritted when Magento is updated.

Thanks.

Comment: where you want to use this request? be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you have several options for how you can implement this. The product meta title comes from the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class specifically seeking out the HTML head block instance (`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`) from the layout object (`Mage_Core_Model_Layout`) and setting its 'title' property to the product model's (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`) getMetaTitle() value.

Based on this, you could rewrite the product model class and add a custom getMetaTitle() method which includes your prefix/suffix logic. You could also rewrite the product view block's `_prepareLayout()` method to include your prefix and suffix. You could also do this through observers or by rewriting the catalog product view controller.

Comment if you need a hand with any of the above.

Comment: Hi Ben, many thanks for your response. I have created an override under /app/code/local/Override/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php and I want to extend the `__prepareLayout()` method from the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class like you say. This is fine, the only issue I am having is using the XML to get the rewrite to work, would you possibly know how to go about doing this? Many thanks

Comment: <config><global><blocks><catalog><rewrite><product_view>Override_Catalog_Block_Product_View